# Is there any common meaning to a `collects` directory?

Tags: directory-structure

I'm under the impression that there are a bunch of directory names that have common semantics, like (in no particular order):

- `usr`
- `tmp`
- `src`
- `lib`
- `etc`
- `share`
- `opt`
- `bin`
- `sbin`
- `var`
- `data`
- `include`

There are others that may or may not be UNIX-y (e.g. `libexec`) but they show up frequently enough to imply that conventions exist.

I noticed that [Racket uses a `collects` directory](https://github.com/plt/racket/tree/722dc826b86482a5270239d89484817a4723e41a). Is there any other software that uses a `collects` directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Racket has a concept of [collections](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/collects.html). From its website:

> A library is module declaration for use by multiple programs. Racket further groups libraries into collections that can be easily distributed and added to a local Racket installation.

It appears as though the `collects` directory holds collections that are distributed with Racket. To confirm this, I asked a question in the [#racket IRC channel](http://racket-lang.org/community.html). I received a response from a Racket developer.

```
< EvanTeitelman> What is the purpose of the `collects` directory in the
                 Racket git repository?
< [developer]> It used to hold all libraries (aka collections) of Racket
               implemented in Racket.
< EvanTeitelman> soegaard: Are those collections distributed with Racket?
< [developer]> yes
```

Outside of Racket, I have never seen a directory named `collects` used in that manner.